# How to limit access in Amazon S3 files to specific people?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, amazon-s3

I work on a SaaS application where `Creators` can create `Groups` and invite others to their `Group` to **share files**, chat and so on. Only people within specific group should have access to this group's files.
People from other group must not have access to not their group's files.

And of course all files permission should be set to 'Private', i.e. they should not be searchable/visible/accessable by anonymous users of Internet since information in those files is for personal use only.

I am new to Amazon S3 and don't know how to achieve it... Should I create only 1 main bucket? Or create for each group a new Amazon Bucket?

Comment: Hang on! I am not sure if I understand your question. You want to give access restriction in your application, what is to do with the S3? You define your policy at the application layer not anywhere else.

Comment: Yes, I have access restriction in my application. But what if a user from 1st group shares a link to a file, hosted in amazon s3? I don't want anyone except people inside a group to be able to see/download this file simply copy/pasting this link to a browser/download manager.

Comment: One more thing. How do you manage file sharing in your application? For example, do you call the file addresses directly from DB? I mean do you save the addresses to the files in the buckets against the user? like 1 to many kind of relation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not recommended to use AWS **Identity and Access Management (IAM)** for storing application users. Application users should be maintained in a **separate database** (or LDAP, Active directory, etc).

Therefore, creating "one bucket per group" is not feasible, since it is not possible to assign your applications users to permissions within Amazon S3.

The better method would be to **manage permissions within your application**. When a user requests access to a file, the application can determine whether they should be permitted access. If they are permitted, then the application can generate a **Pre-Signed URL**.

A **Pre-Signed URL** permits access to private objects stored on Amazon S3. It is a means of keeping objects secure, yet granting temporary access to a specific object.

When listing available files, your application would generate links that include the pre-signed URL. Then, when a user clicks the link, they can access the file. Then, after a certain time has expired (eg 10 minutes), the link will no longer function. So, if a user shares a link with somebody else, it will probably have timed-out.

See: [Creating a pre-signed URL in Ruby](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkforruby/api/Aws/S3/Presigner.html)